# Spark - extracting single value from DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark DataFrame query that is guaranteed to return single column with single Int value. What is the best way to extract this value as Int from the resulting DataFrame?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use `head`

```
df.head().getInt(0)
```

or `first`

```
df.first().getInt(0)
```

Check [DataFrame](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) scala docs for more details

Comment: Note: `first()` is an alias for `head()`. (for others reading here)

Comment: Any equivalent for this in PySpark?

Comment: In PySpark, you can convert the row to a dict and then look for your key, like: `df.head().asDict()['path']`

Answer (score 7):

This could solve your problem.

```scala
df.map{
    row => row.getInt(0)
}.first()
```

Answer (score 7):

In `Pyspark`, you can simply get the first element if the `dataframe` is single entity with `one column` as a response, otherwise, a whole `row` will be returned, then you have to get `dimension-wise` response i.e. 2 Dimension list like `df.head()[0][0]`

```
df.head()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If we have the spark dataframe as :

```
+----------+
|_c0       |
+----------+
|2021-08-31|
+----------+

x = df.first()[0]
print(x)

2021-08-31
```