# Retrieving a column value from a table to a variable in spark 1.4?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a table with multiple values, I want to retrieve the value of first column from the table and store it in a variable using `spark 1.4 (scala)`. 
Below is what i have tried.

```
//The value of "RatingStartDate" is 2011-07-11 00:00:00.000
val t= out2.select("RatingStartDate").show(1)
println(t)

Output:
()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark - extracting single value from DataFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961971/spark-extracting-single-value-from-dataframe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the `show()` function actually returns a `Unit` implying that it is only used for its side effects (similar to `void` in Java); here the side effect is printing the first row of your dataframe to the console. What you are doing is storing this returned `Unit` type into a variable and printing it, which doesn't really make sense. What I believe you are attempting to do is something like:

```
val t = out2.select("RatingStartDate").first()
```

The `first()` function grabs the first row from your dataframe and you can store this in a variable.

Comment: I want to add two columns but spark 1.4 does not support timestamp numeric operation ex: out2("RatingStartDate")+(out2("RatingStartTime") so what to do now?

Comment: Well adding two columns is supported, but can you provide some more context on what types these columns are as well as what your expected input/outputs are? (Honestly, this might be better asked as a separate question.)

Comment: col1                           col2                              col3                                                                                                                                                                  RatingStartTime   +   RatingStartDate   =       RatingStartDateTime                         2011-07-11 00:00:00.000  +     1900-01-01 14:53:45.000=                  2011-07-11 14:53:45.000          col1,col2 type=Timestamp